# Not Able to Publish A New Version Of Lambda Using Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to deploy a lambda function using terraform and I need to publish a new version every-time i run a terraform apply command.

I lave created a generalised lambda module I my code so I can re-use it to deploy other lambda function as well

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name                  = var.function_name
  description                    = var.description
  role                           = var.arn
  handler                        = var.handler
  memory_size                    = var.memory_size
  runtime                        = var.runtime
  timeout                        = var.timeout
  publish                        = true
  tags                           = var.tags

  # Use a generated filename to determine when the source code has changed.

  filename = var.filename

  source_code_hash               = "${var.source_code_hash}-${uuid()}"

  # Add dynamic blocks based on variables.
```

As you can I have explicitly specified publish = true, but still lambda is getting deployed but version is not getting updated. Can someone please help on this? Thanks!

Tried setting publish = true

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be because of the method you have used to set the 'source_code_hash' attribute. You're appending some uuid to the source_code_hash every time Terraform runs but AWS Lambda doesn't support this. The 'source_code_hash' should be a base64-encoded SHA256 hash of the package file specified with either filename or s3_key.

Try this instead:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambda_code_dir"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  ...
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256
  
}
```

Reference:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/file